# "Descending cohomology, geometrically" by Mazur:

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

(Exist texts of that talk or related texts: http://ttv.mit.edu/collections/harris60/videos/13881-problem-session-barry-mazur ?) Article: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/papers/page37.pdf

Comment: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question

Comment: I believe our edit should be an answer.